# Setting a linewidth table with centered text

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I need to identificate three figures, which should equally divide the linewidth. I tried many solutions, but they can't center the text in each cell. The unique solution that solves the problem is `\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{ccc}`, although the text size becomes large (even with `\tiny`).

The actual solution I'm working on is:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular*}{1\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccc}
    \small{a) $16\times16$ $4$-QAM} & \small{b) $16\times16$ $16$-QAM} & \small{c) $16\times16$ $64$-QAM} 
\end{tabular*}

\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{fig/Mixing_ratio/Q_analysis_16x16_4QAM.eps}
\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{fig/Mixing_ratio/Q_analysis_16x16_16QAM.eps}
\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{fig/Mixing_ratio/Q_analysis_16x16_64QAM.eps}
\caption{BER performance convergence of mixing ratio, $q$, of aSMGS in low number of antennas scenario ($K=N=16$) with: {\bf a)} No restarts ($R_{\rm max} = 1$), $\gamma_{\rm dB}=12$dB, 4-QAM and {\bf b)} $R_{\rm max} = 10$, $\gamma_{\rm dB}=18$dB, 16-QAM.}
\label{fig:q_convergence_4-QAM} \end{figure}
```

Which gives:
[image: the text of a), b) and c) need to be centered]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with `subfloat` environment from package `subfig` you not need a table:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\captionsetup[subfloat]{position=top}
\centering
\subfloat[$16\times16$ $4$-QAM] {\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{fig/Mixing_ratio/Q_analysis_16x16_4QAM.eps}}\hfill
\subfloat[$16\times16$ $16$-QAM] {\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{fig/Mixing_ratio/Q_analysis_16x16_16QAM.eps}}\hfill
\subfloat[$16\times16$ $64$-QAM] {\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{fig/Mixing_ratio/Q_analysis_16x16_64QAM.eps}}
    \caption{BER performance convergence of mixing ratio, $q$, of aSMGS in low number of antennas scenario ($K=N=16$) with: {\bf a)} No restarts ($R_{\rm max} = 1$), $\gamma_{\rm dB}=12$dB, 4-QAM and {\bf b)} $R_{\rm max} = 10$, $\gamma_{\rm dB}=18$dB, 16-QAM.}
\label{fig:q_convergence_4-QAM} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

- with `subfloat` you can referee sub figures in the text, just add labels to sub floats titles, for example `
- if you like to have sub caption on the top only in this figure than include `\captionsetup[subfloat]{position=top}` in figure environment, in oposite case, when all sub figures should have captions on the top, move this settings to document preamble

Answer (score 0):

Make the labels into part of figures, i.e., make the content `a) $16\times16$ $4$-QAM` to part of the figure and follow the below suggestion:

```
\hbox to \textwidth{\includegraphics{fig1.eps}\hfill\includegraphics{fig2.eps}\hfill \includegraphics{fig3.eps}
```

This will split the horizontal space for each figures equally.